# Map an array to render components after data is fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I got this error message, and I found that might be the problem of api, it's slower than compiler execute the html part.

If I want to render the components after data is fetched, how should I do that? I've tried so many places to put async function, but all failed. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import api from '../api/index'

function MyAssets() {
    const [assetData, setAssetData] = useState({})


    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchData = async ()=> {
            const data = await api.getSData()  <-------------! I call the API here
            setAssetData({
                budget: data.data[0].budget,
                assets: data.data[0].assets
            })
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    function AssetRow(props) {
        return (
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{props.item.symbol}</th>
                <td>{props.item.amount}</td>
                <td>Price</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }

    return (
      {
        assetData.assets.map((item, index) => {        <------! I try to map an array here
          return <AssetRow key={index} item={item} />;
        }
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: are you sure that ```data.data[0].assets``` is an array ? you can try ```assetData && assetData.assets.map```

Comment: Have you tried separating out the fetchData function (not including the setAssetData) part, so that it returns an object `{budget: ..., assets: ....}`, and then call that function within `const [assetData, setAssetData] = useState( fetchData() )`? That way you'll have the result as the initial state of assetData (and since you're only calling the useEffect on the initial render)

Answer (score 2):

The render phase is called before all effects. So in the first render (when **MyAssets** component is mounted) assetData has **{}** as value, so there is no **assets** attribute to access and is undefined.

Try by initializing with default value like

`const [assetData, setAssetData] = useState({ assets: [] })`